# WF 4.0.1 PersistableIdle won't fire

Tags: database, persistence, workflow-foundation

So I have a Console Application creating and starting a WF4 State Machine. I put the InstanceStore, the database is ready and an activity will put the machine to sleep when needed. Now, all is good, but when the machine goes to Idle, it actually goes to Idle and not to PersistableIdle, which is needed to persist the workflow into the database...
I tested a few things... connection string etc. but I found nothing weird...

Any idea of what to do when the machine doesn't want to go to PersistableIdle?

Thanks for the help. If you need any code, I'll put it but I can assure you it is very standard stuff...